# ADO.NET: convert a DataTable to an array of DataRows

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm using ADO.NET and C#, and I want to convert a DataTable object into an array of DataRows. What is an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My first question would be why? The request makes no sense.

The answer is:

```
DataRow[] rows = myDataTable.Select();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to copy any rows with RowState == DataRowState.Deleted

Comment: @Alex: That's because a row with a `Deleted` state is no longer considered to be part of the table. If you'd like to verify, compare `.Select()` with `table.Rows.Count`. You'll find they're identical.

Comment: It's weird but dt.Select() sometimes changes rows order when you use it inside async/await. don't know why
so i use dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray()  and it work's perfect

Answer (score 2):

Actually the DataTable has a property called Rows, witch provides the methods to do this.

You can accomplish this doing:

```
List<System.Data.DataRow> r = d.Rows.AsQueryable().OfType<System.Data.DataRow>().ToList();
```

Comment: Voted up cuz I was looking for the "LINQ" way... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

DataTable.Select() gives you an array of DataRows. You can use this as an array

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dr() As DataRow = dt.Select()
```

In case you want an ArrayList, you can

```
public ArrayList ConvertDT(ref DataTable dt)
{
        ArrayList converted = new ArrayList(dt.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
                converted.Add(row);
        }
        return converted;
}
```

I have not used the dt.rows.CopyTo function. maybe that works also.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see the contents as a string, use this code:

```
string.Join(",", dataTable.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(row => row.ItemArray))
```